# How to color math symbols?

Tags: math-mode, macros, color

One can use the command such as `\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{boundary}` to color the word "boundary" in a document.

Here is my **question**:

How to color the math symbols in `$$`? For example, can one turn `$C^{2}$` into red in LaTeX?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

`\textcolor` from the `xcolor` package also works in mathmode, even if the name says otherwise. You can also use `$ \color{<color>} C^2 $`. It sets the color for the rest of the current scope (group).

Examples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

$ \color{red} C^2 $

$ \color{yellow} A = \textcolor{blue}{B} \mathbin{\textcolor{red}{-}} \textcolor{green}{C} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `\mathbin` must be wrapped around the coloured, binary `-` here, as Leo Liu pointed out in his comment, to set the correct spacing again. The coloring changes the math type so they spacing would be different.

Answer (score 87):

An addition to Martin Scharrer's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21600/16967).

`\textcolor` has a side effect in math, that the contents is put in curly braces (see definition of `\@textcolor`). The color implementation of package `color` is based on groups (the color is restored at the end of the group automatically), but curly braces also make a subformula in math. This affects the horizontal spacing, since the `\textcolor` now acts as ordinary math atom. This can be avoided by using `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` instead of the curly braces:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}% or package color

\begin{document}

\[
  \color{yellow} A
  \begingroup\color{magenta}=\endgroup
  \textcolor{blue}{B}
  \mathbin{\color{red}-}% shorter than \mathbin{\textcolor{red}{-}}
  \textcolor{green}{C}
  \begingroup\color{cyan}+\endgroup
  D
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A macro `\mathcolor` can be defined, which can be used instead of `\textcolor` in math:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\mathcolor#1#{\@mathcolor{#1}}
\def\@mathcolor#1#2#3{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}#3%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  \color{yellow} A
  \mathcolor{magenta}{=}
  \mathcolor{blue}{B}
  \mathcolor{red}{-}
  \mathcolor{green}{C}
  \mathcolor{cyan}{+}
  D
\]
\end{document}
```

Or the definition of `\textcolor` can be fixed:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@textcolor}[3]{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}#3%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: N.B. The provided `\mathcolor` definition should no longer be used, as its `\def` will overwrite the current one, which now exists in modern `xcolor` and `color` packages.

Comment: How to handle the use of `&` with `\color{} \begingroup \endgroup`?

Answer (score 10):

In sufficiently new version of LaTeX, simply load `xcolor` package and use `\mathcolor`. Refer to `texdoc mathcolor` for documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
$\mathcolor{red}{1}\mathcolor{blue}{+}\mathcolor{green}{2}$

$1+2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This has certain advantages compared to other approaches:

- Spacing is usually more correct:

  ```
  \[\textcolor{blue}{f}^2_3 \ne \mathcolor{blue}{f}^2_3\]
  ```

  [image: colored f^2_3]

  ```
  \[5\textcolor{blue}{+}6 \ne 5\mathcolor{blue}{+}6\]
  ```

  [image: 5+6]
- Other surprises with `\color`:

  ```
  \[ f^{\color{blue} 2}_3 \]
  ```

  [image: f^2_3 misaligned]

---

(Of course, if you try hard enough to break it it won't work: [Why do optional arguments of commands affect spacing of \mathcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/701416/250119) but usually it would)