# Beamer \textcolor space in math mode problem

Tags: beamer, math-mode, color

Why in the second case the spacing is correct and not in the first ?

Maybe not fully correct in the second between `+` and `u` ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
5 \only<1>{\textcolor{red}{+}}6+7
\end{equation*}

  \begin{equation*}
          \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= \only<1>{\textcolor{red}{+u(n,t)}u(n+1,t)}\only<2>{u(n,t)\textcolor{red}{u(n+1,t)}} -u(n,t)u(n-1,t)
  \end{equation*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Compare `5+6+7` with 5{+}6+7`. Curly braces around `+` (and other math operators) eat space around it. The same happens when you change their color an way as you do.

Comment: Thank you, I know now why it doesn't work. How to change the color a math operator ?

Comment: the answer is in the comment of this question : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-to-color-math-symbols

Comment: One way is manually add the space araound signs, something like `{\color{red}\,+\,}`. For better way ... temporary I haven't clue.

Comment: A group without making a subformula: `\begingroup\color{red}+\endgroup`.

Comment: Martin Scharrer answer works fine, please feel free to add yours, I'll upvote them. And thank you Zarko to have pointed the problem.