# Changing color in math mode

Tags: math-mode, color

If I want to write the symbols `$\iota_1\cdot \gamma$` in, say, red, how would I do that?

Comment: [How to color math symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21598)

Comment: what did you try? surely the first thing to try would be `$\color{red}\iota_1\cdot \gamma$` which works?