# Change properties of line in a mathematical fraction

Tags: math-mode, color

How to adjust the **width** and the **color** of the line in between numerator and denominator in a mathematical fraction? I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-to-color-math-symbols) but it does not help.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\color{red} y = \frac{x}{z}
\end{equation}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be an awkward way to do it but you can color the fraction and then return the numerator and denominator to black:

```
$ y = \color{red} \frac{\color{black} x}{\color{black} z}$
```

In general you would need some foolproof way to ensure that the red color doesn't leak out elsewhere. This might (or might not) do it:

```
\def\redfrac#1#2{\begingroup \color{red}
  \frac{\color{black}#1}{\color{black}#2}\endgroup}
```

Of course, a proper definition would use whatever color is current rather than force black. However, that exceeds my understanding of the internals of the color or xcolor package.

Comment: How do you use `\redfrac`? Also, what about the width of the line?

Comment: $y=\redfrac{x}{z}

Answer (score 3):

You have to typeset the fraction with the selected color and go back to the previous color for the numerator and denominator.

With `\genfrac` you can set the thickness of the fraction bar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\colorfrac}[4][]{%
  \begingroup
  \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
  \textcolor{#2}{%
    \genfrac{}{}{#1}{}{\textcolor{currentcolor}{#3}}{\textcolor{currentcolor}{#4}}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\[
y=\colorfrac[1pt]{red}{x}{z}
\]

\leavevmode\color{blue}Some blue text
\[
y=\colorfrac[2pt]{red}{x}{z}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `\genfrac`! Could I just use `\genfrac` when needed, instead of adding many things to the preamble?

Comment: @luchonacho You need `\usepackage{amsmath}`