# Latex Equations: Colour all instances of symbol

Tags: equations, color, syntax-highlighting

I (and most humans) find equations a lot easier to read when certain variables are highlighted.  For example:

```
$$
0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial\color{blue}{z_l}}\big(\|h(z_{l-1})\cdot w_l-\color{blue}{z_l}\| + \lambda \| h(\color{blue}{z_l})\cdot w_{l+1} - z_{l+1}\| \big) 
$$
```

Gives a visually appealing:
[image]

My question: Is there some way to do this without explicitly filling the equation with these `\color` commands?  Ideally, I would not have to change the equations at all, and could just define a block around the equation that takes care of the colouring.  I'm looking for something like defining a block of code where you automatically replace all instances of `z_l` with `\color{blue}{z_l}`.

To be clear, I am aware of the "Find -> Replace" function of most editors, but this isn't what I'm looking for - I want to be decorate my equations without messing up the equation code itself.

Comment: You could just define `\def\z1{\ensuremath{\color{blue} z_1}}` (untested) and use it as `\z1` or something like that.

Comment: Please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: @Sebastiano Please elaborate, in what sense is the link related to this question?

Comment: It would be easy to make `z` blue without requiring any markup, quite a bit trickier (to the point that I wouldn't do it in a real document) to make `z_l` all go blue. (unless you want all `l` to go blue, which seems not to be the case as `w_l` is black).

Comment: Aside: Don't use `$$` in a LaTeX document to initiate and terminate display-math mode. See the postings [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$ … $$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001) for more information on this topic.

Comment: Please clarify whether (a) only instances of `z_l` or (b) all instances of `z_{...}` should be colored in blue.

Comment: For this it's fine to be just `z_l` (doesn't have to get in to pattern matching)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You're fully right, but I corrected it in my answer. Sadly I wasn't able to edit my comment anymore...

Comment: Relying on string matching is quite fragile -- what if you write `z_{l}` or `z^2_l`?

Comment: potential duplicate: [How to color math symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21598/579)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(edited/simplified the code after OP clarified that only `z_l` instances need to be colored for now)

You could achieve your objective by using LuaLaTeX and taking a preprocessor-based approach, as is done in the following example.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\usepackage{luacode}
% The lua function 'color_zl' does the actual work
\begin{luacode}
function color_zl ( s ) 
  s = string.gsub ( s , "z_l" , "\\textcolor{blue}{%0}" )
  return s
end
\end{luacode}

% The lua function is assigned to 'process_input_buffer' callback:
\newcommand{\ZColorOn}{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
  "process_input_buffer", color_zl , "color_zl" )}}
\newcommand{\ZColorOff}{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
  "process_input_buffer", "color_zl" )}}

\begin{document}
\ZColorOn % turn on automatic coloring of "z_l" terms
\[
0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial z_l}\bigl(
          \norm[\big]{h(z_{l-1})\cdot w_l-z_l} 
+ \lambda \norm[\big]{h(z_l)\cdot w_{l+1} - z_{l+1}} \bigr) 
\]

\ZColorOff % turn off automatic coloring of "z_l" terms
\[
0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial z_l}\bigl(
          \norm[\big]{h(z_{l-1})\cdot w_l-z_l} 
+ \lambda \norm[\big]{h(z_l)\cdot w_{l+1} - z_{l+1}} \bigr) 
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* If you wanted to typeset in blue *all* instances of `z` with *any* subscript, not just `z_l`, you should modify the Lua function by enabling a couple of pattern-matching operations:

```
function color_zl ( s ) 
  s = string.gsub ( s , "z_%b{}" , "\\textcolor{blue}{%0}" )
  s = string.gsub ( s , "z_(%w)" , "\\textcolor{blue}{%0}" )
  return s
end
```

The first pattern, `%b{}`, matches a matching pair of curly braces with any content. The second pattern, `%w`, matches a single alphanumeric character, e.g., `l`, `1`, etc.

Comment: Nice!  Do you know if this can be done in some kind of environment (something like `\begin{ZColor} ... \end{ZColor}`)?

Comment: @Peter - Certainly! Just add the following code to the preamble: `\newenviroment{ZColor}{\ZColorOn}{\ZColorOff}`

Answer (score 5):

Just try to make your own definition for that. As a starting point a example for your case:

[image: equation]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\def\zl{{\ensuremath{\color{blue} z_l}}}

\begin{document}
\[0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial\zl}\big(\|h(z_{l-1})\cdot w_l-\zl\| + \lambda \| h(\zl)\cdot w_{l+1} - z_{l+1}\| \big) \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not bad but it still requires modifying the equation - making the equation code unportable.  Also I would only like to do this in a context - I may not want to have all instances of `z_l` go blue in the entire document.

Comment: @Peter You can do this def right before the equation and copy it to another file too (it's portable). If you later on want to have it back in black just do a `\def\zl{\ensuremath z_l}`.

Answer (score 5):

You do not have to have markup (or Lua) to colour math tokens for example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\mathchardef\zmath\mathcode`z
\mathcode`z="8000

{\makeatletter
\def~{\@ifnextchar_{\zzm}{\zmath}}
\catcode`z\active
\global\let z~
}

\def\zzl{l}
\def\zzm_#1{%
 \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\zzl
  \textcolor{blue}{\zmath_{l}}%
  \else
    \zmath_{#1}%
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\[
0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial z_l}\bigl(\|h(z_{l-1})\cdot w_l-z_l\| + 
\lambda \| z_l)\cdot w_{l+1} - z_{l+1}\| \big) 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, although I'm a bit baffled as to what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

I was quite fed up with writing `X_{\mathit{y}}` to get proper index y following the variable X. You seem to have simillar problem. My solution, adapted to your case, was:

```
\newcommand[2][blue]{\foo}{{\ensuremath{\color{#1}#2}}}
```

And usage is simple:

`Variable \foo{b} is emphasized blue and variable \foo[red]{r} is emphasized red.`

Comment: Your opening sentence is quite confusing: `X_y` and `X_{\mathit{y}}` should produce the exact same output, no? Also, the OP wrote that "I want to ... decorate my equations without messing up the equation code itself". Wouldn't replacing all instances of `z_l` with `\foo{x_l}` constitute an example of "messing up the equation code itself"?