# How to change colour within equation?

Tags: equations, color, amsmath, article

I’m using article class, and I want to change colour within the equation tag, multiple times. I found that using mathmode I can change colour, but I want to use equation tag instead. After having the multicolour equation I will link the file to a beamer for a presentation.

Is this possible (successfully linking changed colours from article to beamer as well)? If so, how?

So in my imagination it must be like in the visual. The visual is from

```
$ \color{yellow} A = \textcolor{blue}{B} \mathbin{\textcolor{red}{-}} \textcolor{green}{C} $
```

[image]
However, I need for example below. This doesn’t work for me.

```
\begin{equation}
\color{red}A=\color{blue}B-\color{green}C
\end{equation}
```

Comment: check: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-to-color-math-symbols

Comment: colour is the same in inline math `$` and in a display `equation` so it isn't clear what your question is?

Comment: @kneazle Can you please make a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates what does not work for you?

Comment: I’m sorry everyone, what I ask is working now. I must have written it somehow wrong.