# How to change color of fonts in this code?

Tags: color

```
\documentclass[12pt, french]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed, etoolbox}
\colorlet{framecolor}{VioletRed4}



\begin{document}




        Soit f une application linéaire alors:
    \[\forall x,y\in G,\ f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: [How to color math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21598/134144) might be related.

Comment: @leandriss, Yes

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt, french]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed, etoolbox}
\colorlet{framecolor}{VioletRed4}



\begin{document}

\color{blue}%%change the color name what you want



        Soit f une application linéaire alors:
    \[\forall x,y\in G,\ f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: As this answer currently stands, the `\color{blue}` command will change the color of *all* the text in the document from that point onwards - probably not what the OP intended. To make it only apply to a small part, it needs to be enclosed in curly braces, like `... normal text {\color{blue}  ... blue text} ... normal text`.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker Thanks for your notification, but the `OP` doesn't mention anything about his requirement, and he just pasted the text, so I thought that he want to change the `color` for the entire text, hence I gave suggestion based on my assumption...If he want to apply `color` for `some particular text,` then he should follow `Sango`'s suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Took leandriis reference to [How to color math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-to-color-math-symbols)

And made this:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, french]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed, etoolbox}
\colorlet{framecolor}{VioletRed4}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}




        Soit f une application linéaire alors:
    \[\color{red} \forall x,y\in \textcolor{blue}{G},\ f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y\]


\end{document}
```

Got this:

[image: Result]