# Knowledge package coloring

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, color

I am having a somewhat complex issue with the `knowledge` package. A MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{knowledge}

\hypersetup{ % Set up hyperref options
    colorlinks=true,
}

\knowledgestyle{no}{color=.}

\knowledgedirective*{automatic in command}{autoref,style=no,intro style=no}

\knowledgenewcommand{\foo}{\cmdkl{foo}}

% Colors in math mode, with correct spacing
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-to-color-math-symbols

\makeatletter

\def\mathcolor#1#{\@mathcolor{#1}}
\def\@mathcolor#1#2#3{%
    \protect\leavevmode
    \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}#3%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\targetcolor}[1]{\mathcolor{green}{#1}}

\begin{document}
  
  \section{A section}
  \label{sec:sec}

  \Cref{sec:sec} is a section
  \[\intro*\foo\]
  \[\foo\]
  \[\targetcolor{\foo}\]

\end{document}
```

First, I’d still like to have internal links – such as the section reference – colored. So AFAIK I have to set `colorlinks=true`.

Now the issue is that the `knowledge` package does *a lot* of linking. The main use I’d like to have for this is to have all notations (such as `foo` here) refer to their definition, so that people can go look them up if they are unsure of their meaning. So far, so good.

I definitely do not want to have all those colored, because that would turn most of my mathematics into the link color – not very informative. Now `knowledge` provides the `knowledgestyle` command to give a specific color to each knowledge command. So I could just put `black` in there, so that `foo` is printed in black.

Now the issue is that later on I want to have different parts of equations colored – I’m doing programming languages theory, that’s basically syntax highlighting. So I define the `targetcolor` macro, and use it. But then this clashes with the two former: If I set the `knowledgestyle` to `black`, I lose because `foo` is black instead of green. If I do not set `knowledgestyle`, then the link color wins again and `foo` turns red.

A solution would be to deactivate link colors in math environments. But I do not know how to do that. I searched around and found `AtBeginEnvironment`, but I am not an expert enough to understand how to use it with mathematical environments (are these actually evene environments?).

Comment: I’d like to add the `knowledge` tag, but apparently I do not have enough reputation. Maybe someone with the right authorizations can do that for me?

Comment: you could try `\everydisplay{\hypersetup{allcolors=.}}`. Side remark: the next xcolor version will define a \mathcolor command.

Comment: This seems to do the trick! Given the name of the command, I guess it only works in displayed math? Is there an equivalent for inline mathematics?

Comment: Nevermind, some searching did the trick now that I know about `\everydisplay` :) It’s `everymath`. Do you want to give this as an answer, so that I can accept it properly? Otherwise I’ll self-answer, but I want to give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `\everydisplay{\hypersetup{allcolors=.}}` and  `\everymath{\hypersetup{allcolors=.}}`. Then hyperref will pick up the current color for the links. (Completly disabling the coloring doesn't work, this needs the new hyperref driver from pdfmanagement-testphase).

Be aware that other packages or code can overwrite this.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, maybe more precise in its scope, is to use a modified version of the `\cmdkl` macro which deactivates link colors:

```
\newcommand\uncolor[1]{\begingroup\hypersetup{allcolors=.}#1\endgroup}
\newcommand\ucmdkl[1]{\uncolor{\cmdkl{#1}}}

\knowledgenewcommand{\foo}{\ucmdkl{foo}}
```

Note that the `wrap=` directive of knowledge does not work since it is applied innermost, which means here inside the linking command.