# textcolor and displaystyle

Tags: equations, color, displaystyle

I need to color a portion of a displayed equation, but when I do that the equation gets turned into \textstyle instead of \displaystyle.  Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb, xcolor}
\begin{document}
\[
\prod_{a\in A} a
\]
\[
\textcolor{red}{\prod_{a\in A} a}
\]
\[
\textcolor{red}{\prod}_{a\in A} a
\]
\end{document}
```

In the third example (where the error appears) I tried to insert \displaystyle at the beginning, to no avail.  I am confused; your help is most appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: use \mathcolor.

Comment: Thanks @fischer, but  the second-last comment in  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-to-color-math-symbols  seems to suggest that \mathcolor should not be used --- perhaps I misunderstodd that comment?

Comment: That is old. In a current latex \mathcolor is predefined.

Comment: Thanks @fischer.  Could you provide a MWE?  I tried to use \[ \mathcolor{red}{\prod}_{a\in A} a \]  in my MWE and got the error "Undefined control sequence" for \mathcolor.   I am using TeX Live 2022.

Comment: the code was added 2022/06/12 v2.14 to xcolor, and im 2022/06/01 to latex, so it should work in a texlive 2022 which has been updated.

Comment: Thanks @fischer.  I am using pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022) and still got the error.   If you could provide a MWE I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: the pdftex version is not relevant. Check in the log the version of the latex format and of xcolor.

Comment: @fischer:  Aaah  my log file says:  Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13  and  (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.5.30).  This is a work machine and it would be difficult to get the packages updates.  Could you offer an alternative solution?  Thank!

Comment: In older versions, you can just copy paste the definition of mathcolor from this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261480/250119 .